# get the value from the dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am working with Round Robin (RR). I am building random Round-Robin value. I get the time for the RR randomly. In the first run it shows me the current values that  i have in the list.  but when it goes to run for the second time it just say  the ***index is not presented in the dictionary key***. I am trying to fix this problem I have add the time and the quantum tim that the algorithm reduce the value from the dictionary  and return back to the dictionary it the value is > 0.

```
Dictionary<int, int> waytosave = new Dictionary<int, int>();

    List<int> randomListxCoor = new List<int>();
    List<int> randomListyCoor = new List<int>();



    int xCoor;
    int yCoor;

    Random coor = new Random();
    Random setTimeRandom = new Random();
    int randomTimeSetting;

    int NodeIndex = 0;
    Graphics graphDraw;
    Graphics drawLine;
    int TimeToProcess = 0;
    string NodeName = "";
    int QuantumTime = 1;
    int TotalRouterTime = 0;
    int NextNodeToProcess = 0;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    this.graphDraw  = this.panel1.CreateGraphics();
        this.drawLine = this.panel1.CreateGraphics();

    }

    private void btnRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int nodesNumber = (int)this.numNodes.Value;
        SolidBrush getNodesDrawn = new SolidBrush(Color.LightYellow);
        for (int x = 1; x <= nodesNumber; x++)
        {
            xCoor = coor.Next(0, 700);
            yCoor = coor.Next(0, 730);
            if (!randomListxCoor.Contains(xCoor))
            {
                randomListxCoor.Add(xCoor);

            }
            if (!randomListyCoor.Contains(xCoor))
            {
                randomListyCoor.Add(yCoor);

            }

            randomTimeSetting = setTimeRandom.Next(1, 10);

            //Draw the line from main Node to the other Nodes

            Pen linePen = new Pen(Color.DarkMagenta, 2);

            drawLine.DrawLine(linePen, 350, 360, xCoor, yCoor);
            drawLine = this.panel1.CreateGraphics();
            graphDraw.FillEllipse(getNodesDrawn, xCoor - 5, yCoor - 5, 15, 12);



            //Add the values t the Dictionaries and the List.

            waytosave.Add(x, randomTimeSetting);
        }
    }
    private void btnRunTIme_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.QuantumTime = (int)this.numQuanrum.Value;
        this.ComputeTotalNodeTime();
        this.timerRoundRobin.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void timerRoundRobin_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.NodeIndex = this.GetNextNodeToProcess();
        if (this.NodeIndex >= 0)
        {
            this.waytosave[this.NodeIndex] -= this.QuantumTime;
```

here at this point it getting crashed. I tried to fixed the number of iteration but if i change the number of iterations it will not go through all the values in the dictionary.

```
                if (this.waytosave[this.NodeIndex] < 0)
                                          {
                this.waytosave[this.NodeIndex] = 0;
            }
            this.NodeName = this.NodeIndex.ToString();
            this.TimeToProcess = this.waytosave[this.NodeIndex];

            this.txtOutput.Text += "\r\r\n" + " Time Remaining:   "
                                             + this.TimeToProcess
                                             + "Router name:     "
                                             + this.NodeName;
        }
        else
        {
            this.timerRoundRobin.Enabled = false;

            this.txtOutput.Text += "\r\r\n" + "  Ends x " + TotalRouterTime.ToString();

            return;

        }
    }

    private int GetNextNodeToProcess()
    {
        int NextNodeIndex = -1;
        if (NextNodeToProcess >= this.waytosave.Count)
        { NextNodeToProcess = 0; }
        for (int i = NextNodeToProcess; i < this.waytosave.Count; i++)
        {
            if (this.waytosave[i] > 0)
            {
                NextNodeIndex = i;
                break;
            }

        }
        NextNodeToProcess++;
        return NextNodeIndex;
    }

    private void ComputeTotalNodeTime()
    {
        this.TotalRouterTime = 0;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> item in this.waytosave)
        {
            this.TotalRouterTime += item.Value;

            this.txtOutput.Text += "\r\r\n" + " Time Remaining:   "
                                         + item.Value
                                         + "Router name:     "
                                         + item.Key;
        }

    }
```

I am trying to fix this value from days but i have no  success. the problem that in cannot read the first value from the dictionary. How can I solve this problem. Can you please give me some Hence.

Comment: How about providing a [sscce](http://sscce.org/)? At the moment, there seems to be a lot of code that is not related to your question. Try to keep it to the bare minimal.

Comment: I post the part the show the functionality  of my code and how  i am gitting the values and where I am storing them